# Mysterious MYSQL syntax error - works fine in phpMyadmin, not on page

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to get a list of expenses from a certain date, I can execute this SQL fine in PHPMyAdmin but on the page I am receiving a MYSQL Syntax Error.

The Code:

```
$full_date = date('d M Y', strtotime($date));

$get_expenses = mysql_query("SELECT Sum(cost) AS expense FROM expenses WHERE date = $full_date")or die(mysql_error());

$expenses = mysql_fetch_array( $get_expenses );

echo $expenses['expense'];
```

The syntax error I receive is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Apr 2015' at line 1

I have checked to see the value of `$expenses['expense']` and it returns a valid date. In PHPMyAdmin I can execute this SQL with no problems. Any pointers? Cheers!

Comment: As early as now, stop using mysql extension and move to mysql. And dont forget to escape your inputs.

Comment: Must be `...date = '$full_date'`. Use a single tick (`'`). You can only not use it if the variable contains number only (`int`) and the column name for your condition is also `int`. `$full_date` variable must also contains a formatted date of `YYYY-MM-DD`. And refrain from using deprecated `mysql_* functions` and instead use `mysqli_* prepared statement`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this,before that convert your date to respective format then do like this,

```
$get_expenses = mysql_query("SELECT Sum(cost) AS expense FROM expenses WHERE date = '$full_date'")or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Sum(cost) AS expense FROM expenses WHERE date = 13 Apr 2015
```

is *not* a valid query, but it's what you get from that expression.

You should surround the value with quotes, such as with:

```
$full_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
$get_expenses = mysql_query("SELECT Sum(cost) AS expense FROM expenses WHERE date = '$full_date'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: You'll get `04` with a common `m` but `Apr` with a capital `M`